# How to call custom Javascript functions from an AngularJS controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a standard function in `app.js` defined as follows:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'], function () {

});


$(document).ready(function () {
    // standard error box
    function showError(title, content) {
        $.bigBox({
            title: title,
            content: content == null ? "An error occurred.<br /><br />If this error persists, please contact support." : content,
            color: "#C46A69",
            //timeout: 6000,
            icon: "fa fa-warning shake animated",
            //number: "1",
            timeout: 3000
        });
    }
});
```

In an AngularJS controller method, I want to be able to call showError():

```
                    someFunction()
                        .success(function (result) {
                            // great!
                        })
                        .error(function (error) {
                            // call standard error message function
                            showError("Update Failed"); // use default error message
                        });
```

I know app.js is loaded, but I am not sure on how to call some of my own custom functions within the context of AngularJS.

There is a vestigial function in the `angular.module` definition, as I tried putting my custom function in there to see if this would work - no.

What is the appropriate way of accomplishing this?

**-- UPDATE --**

To clarify, I will want to invoke many custom functions like `showError()` and `showSuccess()` from many controllers, so these functions should have global scope, and not confined to one specific Angular controller.

Comment: Can't you just remove them from the `document.ready` and define them at a global scope?

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could just call it from anywhere since it's javascript, however you should never use global functions so I would create an alert service with the functions I need, and then use it by injecting it inside the controllers.

```
angular.module('yourModule').factory('alertService', function() {
    return {
        showError : function() {
            $.bigBox({
                title: title,
                content: content == null ? "An error occurred.<br /><br />If this error    persists, please contact support." : content,
                color: "#C46A69",
                //timeout: 6000,
                icon: "fa fa-warning shake animated",
                //number: "1",
                timeout: 3000
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can inject it inside any controller and use it:

```
angular.module('yourModule').controller('yourController', function($scope, alertService) {
   someFunction().success(function (result) {
       // great!
   }).error(function (error) {
       // call standard error message function
       alertService.showError("Update Failed"); // use default error message
   });
});
```

You can then add more functions to the service like `showSuccess` and it has the advantage of requiring changes in just a single place if you decide some time in the future to replace the plugin with another or make any changes to the service.

**Warning**

Creating directives for any jQuery plugin integration is the way to go in 99% of cases. I believe a simple `alertService` can "bend" the rules in this case as to avoid overcomplication by broadcasting and catching events inside a directive.

Comment: Why are you firing off a jQuery plugin in a service? Any DOM manipulation should be in a directive.

Comment: Because it's the type of plugin that fires off an alert, it does not require binding to an existing html element, so I don't see the need to bind it to the template

Comment: It still does DOM manipulation, thus requiring to be in a directive.

Comment: In this case I don't really agree, alerts are more stand alone than typical jQuery plugins, I would agree with you for most plugins, the only other way I can see this work with a directive, is to have a listener inside the directive, and fire events that the directive catches, and I think that's just unnecessary complication. Keeping it simple is sometimes the way to go.

Comment: You think it's an unnecessary complication to decouple your code? This isn't just an "alert" it's obviously a jQuery plugin that creates an alert box on the DOM. That kind of behavior is exactly what directives are for.

Comment: How is my code more coupled than yours? You just have an extra step of creating a directive that helps with... ? I'm gonna have to disagree with you here.

Comment: In that case, as per my comment to @David 's answer below, it seems like a lot of overhead in creating a directive for every custom function.  If this is the recommended way, can I see an example of this?

Comment: So is the above answer 'wrong', in terms of Angular rules, `myService.showError()` as it does do DOM manipulation (all-be-it through a plugin)?  So custom function that don't manipulate the DOM - use a factory - yes?  Then what is the implementation code for custom functions that DO manipulate the DOM - conforming to Angular's rules?

Comment: Even if it's a plugin in, it needs to go in a directive. You use a service or a factory to handle your logic. Then you find a way to pass this logic to the view. You can event listen or you can simply hand it off via scope.

Comment: @DavidEast Actually dialogs, alert boxes are the exceptions to the rule that all DOM manipulation should be in a controller. See Angular-UI's $dialog service for example.