# Angularjs - Factory service not able to access $scope objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory

Based on the top answer of the question asked at : [How to call custom Javascript functions from an AngularJS controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22080262/how-to-call-custom-javascript-functions-from-an-angularjs-controller).

I tried following code:

```
<body ng-app="FDAApp" ng-controller="formController">
<form ng-submit="login()">
    <input type="submit" ng-click="ngSubmit()">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var app = angular.module('FDAApp', []);
    angular.module('FDAApp').factory('MyService', function($http) {
        var sessionKey='';
        return {
            sessionKey: sessionKey,
            login: function()
            {
                sessionKey="ABCD";
            }
        }
    });

    app.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache, $interval, $timeout, MyService) {

        $scope.sessionKey = '';
        $scope.sessionKey = MyService.sessionKey;

        $scope.login = function () {
            MyService.login();
            console.log($scope.sessionKey);
        }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Problem: I am not able get value of $scope.sessionKey updated. Any help?

Comment: not 100% sure what you are asking.. but after you call MyService.login() you will need to call $scope.sessionKey = Myservice.sessionKey again or else the value will not update in your scope.

Comment: Your code has problems related to JavaScript syntax, not AngularJS. In JavaScript, strings are "primitive values", not references. So, your `MyService.sessionKey` will stay equal to `''` and changing the value of local variable `sessionKey` later will not change its value.

Answer (score 0):

When you change a primitive as opposed to a property in an object, $scope.sessionKey will stay at the old session key and the new session key is a new entity that isn't tracked. If you would like to propagate changes that way, you need a different strategy.

You could pass in $scope to MyService to change it from the service, or pass in MyService directly into the scope.

Passing MyService in Scope: http://jsfiddle.net/3mrwLt65/

```
$scope.MyService = MyService

MyService.login()

// now $scope.MyService.sessionKey is your session key.
```

Passing `$scope` to MyService:

In the controller:

```
MyService.login($scope);
```

In the service, the login function will look like:

```
function(scope) {
   scope.sessionKey = <your session key>
}
```

You also might want to do `this.sessionKey = 'ABCD'` as opposed to `sessionKey = 'ABCD'`

Answer (score 0):

Simply invert your design: a service should not change any `$scope`.

Instead, let the service change its own data and expose an object reference:

```
angular.module('FDAApp').factory('MyService', function($http) {
    var session = {
        key: ''
    };

    return {
        session: session,
        login: function()
        {
            session.key = "ABCD";
        }
    }
});

app.controller('formController', function ($scope, $http, $templateCache, $interval, $timeout, MyService) {

    $scope.session = MyService.session;

    $scope.login = function () {
        MyService.login();
        console.log($scope.session.key);
    }
});
```